# add a checkbox to each row inside an XLSX, then delete on upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, checkbox, xlsx

So ATM the user can download an xlsx document, and add new records to it, upload it to the application which updates the DB(with the new records)

I would like to put an option in the excel doc. like a check box (at the beginning of each row) or something like this which, if selected when the doc is uploaded again, it will delete that record from the DB.

I know the logic and how to delete the record but im not sure how to include something like a check box and relate it to each seperate row?

Any one have any ideas?

thank ye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Checkboxes, although you would need to use an "xlsm" (macro-enabled workbook) to insert them. (you could do it without [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) but manually inserting checkboxes and configuring them isnt going to be much fun)

Checkboxes can be "linked" to a cell in your workbook. You'd need to add a Checkbox to each line, and set the linked cell to another cell on that row (preferably all the same column).

You could also make it a lot simpler by doing away with the checkbox and just having a column that you set to true (or any non-empty value) and have your application interpret that to delete the records.

Both methods require you to have an extra column.

Any method will require either an extra column or another sheet with a single column to track the state of each line.